# How to loop over directories with dots and spaces in their names?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory that contains some other directories with a specific pattern. All sub-directories start with a sequential number a dot and a space. Then comes the string `B8Y`, that is always equal and after it another random number. This is a sample folder structure:

```
1. B8Y000037938
2. B8Y000044394
3. B8Y000069434
4. B8Y000078238
5. B8Y000094627
```

Now I want to loop over those directories an call another script. I use this code for the task:

```
for /d %%t in (%MAIN_FOLDER%\*B8Y*) do (
    echo "Processing %%~nt"

    if "%~2"=="" (
        call %PATH_TO_MY_SCRIPT% %%~ft
    ) else (
        call %PATH_TO_MY_SCRIPT% %%~ft %2
    )
)
```

If I do not pass a second parameter to the script, I would expect the output to be like this:

```
Processing 1. B8Y000037938
```

Instead the output is

```
Processing 1
```

and the second script is called with a second parameter that was previously not set and now is `B8Y000037938`.

When I replace `.<space>` with `-` everything works like expected, so I think that `.<space>` is causing the problem. But I don't want to rename all folders manually and even
if it can be done automatically, I would prefer not changing the folder-names. Does anybody know, how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `%%~nxt` in place of `%%~nt`.

~nt means the name of `t`
~nxt means name an extension - and `.whatever` is an extension...

Comment: That did the trick for the output, but not for the call of the other script. However I found the error. The variable has to be wrapped in quotation marks, otherwise the space in the folder-name makes the part after it being interpreted as the second argument. Now it is `call %PATH_TO_MY_SCRIPT% "%%~ft"` instead of `call %PATH_TO_MY_SCRIPT% %%~ft`.